# Can't format the date using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

Can't format the below date using moment.js, the below statement returns `Invalid Date`

```
moment('20171206T062406927Z').format('D-MMM-YYYY');
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: the date value `20171206T062406927Z` is not a recognized format that can be parsed

Comment: Yes Correct the date value should be in this format     '2017-12-06T06:24:06.927Z'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell moment which format your date string is in:

```
moment('20171206T062406927Z', 'YYYYMMDD[T]HHmmssSSSZ', true).format('D-MMM-YYYY');
```

Edit: updated as per @VincenzoC comment to ensure the timestamp is parsed in UTC

Also fix: use `HH` for 24-hour format (not `hh`), and pass a third `true` parameter to ensure the timestamp is parsed in strict mode.

Comment: Please note that `Z` is a valid a valid token, so it should not be escaped.